# Send a post request and ignore the response

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have been trying to set up a modal pop-up using the MVC pattern in an ASP.net Framework (4.8)

I have a paginated table with many rows and working filters (using datatables.net). Each row has a button that uses an ajax call to present a modal popup via a partial view. I can make changes to the data and send that back using a POST request.

But now I don't know how to simply get rid of my partial view while maintaining the original Index page. Here's my code:

**Index View**

```
@model  List<Models.TestModel>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#editModal').modal();
    });

    function editProduct(productId) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Edit/' + productId,
            success: function (data){
                $('#modalWrapper').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<div>
    <table id="JrmTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            @foreach (var i in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => i.Id)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => i.Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => i.Age)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button onclick="editProduct(@i.Id)">ClickMe</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="modalWrapper"></div>
```

Ignoring styling (I'm NOT using bootstrap but have the same class names in my test), here is the partial view that renders perfectly

**PartialView**

```
<div id="editModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1>EDIT</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", Model, FormMethod.Post, null))
                {
                    <p>Id = @Model.Id</p>
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Age)
                    <input type="submit" />
                }
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <p>Footer</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On submission I'm currently passing the edited model to the
**HomeController:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var x = new Data().GetSampleModelList
        return View(x);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var x = new Models.TestModel() { Id = id, Age = 0, Name = "" };
        return PartialView("Edit", x);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Models.TestModel m)
    {
        SaveTheModelMethod();
        // Now What?
    }
}
```

So that's it - I send the post request to an `ActionResult` which expects some sort of return View() etc. - but I don't really want to return anything, I just want to close the partial view (This will leave the table showing old data but that's another question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use AJAX, here is another solution:

JavaScript (modified)

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#editModal').modal();
    });

    function editProduct(productId) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Edit/' + productId,
            success: function (data){
                $('#modalWrapper').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    function saveProduct() {
        // get data from the form
        var payload = {
            Id: $("input[name=Id]").val(),
            Age: $("input[name=Age]").val()
        };
        // post to your edit action
        $.ajax({ 
            url: "/Home/Edit", type: "POST", 
            data: JSON.stringify(payload),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#editModal').hide();
                // CAVEAT: Hide your window using the appropriate command.
                // Here I am just hiding it with jQuery
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

MVC View Snippet (modified)

```
<div class="modal-body">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", Model, FormMethod.Post, null))
{
    <p>Id = @Model.Id</p>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Age)
    <button type="button" id="saveModelButton" onclick="saveProduct()" />
    // This Button changes to have an 'onclick' attribute 
}
 </div>
```

MVC Action

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Edit(Models.TestModel m)
{
    SaveTheModelMethod();
    // Now What?
    return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

Comment: I'll try this first thing tomorrow morning!

Comment: Works absolutely perfectly. Thanks so much!

Comment: glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to reload the page. You should return an empty result.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Models.TestModel m)
{
    SaveTheModelMethod();

    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.emptyresult?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

In my opinion you should reload the Index page because if not your changes won't show up on the UI.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Models.TestModel m)
{
    SaveTheModelMethod();

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.emptyresult?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

**EDIT:** You are getting an empty page because you are using button type submit. You should convert it to a type button and use ajax (You can provide a success of your choice).

```
<script>
    $("#submit_button").click(function () {
        let form = this.parents("form");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: form.attr("action"),
            data: form.serialize()
        });
    });
</script>
```

and change

```
<input type="submit" />
```

to

```
<input type="button" id="submit_button" />
```

*Disclaimer:* written from head, may contain errors.

Comment: I don't want to reload the page though. Ideally I'll use some js to reflect the changes in the selected table row.

Comment: I might be implementing thing wrong but EmptyResult() just gives me an empty page.

Answer (score 1):

I think then you should re-load your list view by redirecting back to your `Index` action.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Models.TestModel m)
{
    SaveTheModelMethod();
    // Now What?
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Then you are back where you started.

Comment: I didn't want to do that because it'll undo any filtering done on the table. In fact if I was going down that route I wouldn't have bothered doing the whole modal popup partial view edit idea, I would just stick with edit buttons redirecting to a new view page :/ probs just wasted two days :D

Comment: then you shouldn't post a form to begin with.  instead of a submit button, put some JavaScript on that button and make and AJAX call to the `Edit(Models.TestModel m)` action.

Comment: i will post a second answer

Comment: Yeah if I don't have to post the form then all the better. I'd like to retain the overall state of the whole index page while 1) sending updated data in the background and 2) use some js to update only selected row in the table with the new data to reflect the changes, without going through the whole index mvc cycle again